What is the physics behind the "wind" one feels when driving?
I was once sitting in a window seat on a bus and I noticed that I only felt wind when the bus was braking or accelerating. I found this strange, because in my experience, a person sitting in the window of a moving bus should feel the "wind", just like when driving a car with the lateral window open. I still don't understand: how was this possible?
The only think that makes sense to me is that air can't be only entering all windows, it must escape somewhere, otherwise the bus/car would explode. But that doesn't explain a window with no air entering nor escaping when in almost uniform motion. Does it? What is the physics behind the "wind" one feels when driving a car at constant velocity?

For clarity: you feel this wind when the car is accelerating/decelerating, while the windows are all closed?

@controlgroup: My window was open. I did not pay attention to the other windows, unfortunetely.

This is a guess.
There is a lot more air in a bus than you might expect. An average bus is $12\,\text{m} \times 3\,\text{m} \times 2.5\,\text{m}$ ($\text{length}\times\text{width}\times\text{height}$). This means it holds about $90\,\text{m}^3$ of air. The density of air is about $1 \,\text{kg}/\text{m}^3$. $90 \,\text{kg}$ is $200 \,\text{lb}$.
With all the windows closed, this air is accelerated when the bus accelerates. The back wall of the bus pushes it forward. The air pressure goes up in the back and down in the front. We can calculate this. If the driver floors it, the bus might accelerate at $0.1 g$ or $1 \,\text{m}/\text{s}^2$.
$$p = \frac{F}{A} = \frac{ma}{A} = \frac{(90 \,\text{kg})( 1.5 \,\text{m}/\text{s}^2)}{7.5 \,\text{m}^2} = 135 \,\text{N}/\text{m}^2$$
This is about $0.0013$ atmospheres, or $1.3$ millibar, or not enough to notice. If the bus were full of water sloshing around, it would be very noticeable. The density of water is $1000$ times bigger than air, so the forces and pressure differences would be $1000$ times bigger. When the bus gets up to speed, the pressure evens out.
Now, suppose a window in front and a window in back are open. And suppose the wind flows in such a way that not much blows in or out when the bus is up to speed.
When the bus accelerates, the $1.3$ millibar higher air pressure is enough to push air out the back window. Storms work with pressure differences about this big. They generate quite a bit of wind over long distances.
The air pressure is lower at the front window, so air is sucked in. Air in the body of the bus flows gently toward the back. You probably don't notice this because the flow is spread over a broad area. The flow through the window is faster.
$$v_\text{window} = v_\text{bus}\frac{A_\text{bus}}{A_\text{window}}$$
So maybe $10$ or $20$ times faster through the window.
